# Assigning an image to imageView in XCode Designer for a macOS application

Tags: xcode, image, macos-high-sierra

I'm making a macOS application and have an imageView element which I wish to hold an image.

You can assign an image in the utilities side bar but when I do I get an error `Could not find image named` and then the name of the image.

[image]

iOS tutorials show an XCAssets folder/directory where you can add your image assets, but my macOS project doesn't have that.

I have a folder in the root called Resources and inside that Interface with the icons and button images in. I have added Resources to the Copy Bundle Resources in the build menu.

I've since added code to assign the image, but how do I do it in a non-programmatic way?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

On the left of Xcode you'll see some tabs. I assume you know what these tabs do. You will go to Assets tab, import from your Mac the photo there and then go to main Edit tab and import it to your project.

If your Xcode doesn't have the Assets tab, you may reinstall it or check for available updates.

Comment: Hi, I've done that. I now have images.xcassets in my project with the play button in a universal @3x, I've gone to the utilities sidebar and added to the image property and I still have the same error? Any ideas?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I can't think something....  I will think and if I think something, I'll let you know.